# Is it necessary LD_LIBRARY_PATH(linux) or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH mac

Tags: c++, compilation, dynamic-linking

I am working with openCV library for computer vision research and when compiling I have had some issues that has make me try to understand how the Operative System links libraries with source code. After looking for a while on the internet to get a good overview and reading manuals for g++/gcc, ld... I have some conclusions that I would like someone with more experience to explain me.

First is the compilation line that I use. This is:

-Input: `g++`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`image-conversion.cpp -o image-conversion`

- Ouput: executable code
- Input: `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
- Output: `-I/opt/local/include/opencv -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_ml -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core`

The library I need for my code is `-lopenhighgui` but I prefer compiling in this way because this library depends on others. The problem is that when I go to `/opt/local/lib` to see the library I have three files:

```
-libopencv_highgui.3.1.0.dylib
-libopencv_highgui.3.1.dylib
-libopencv_highgui.dylib
```

I do not know to which library does `-lopenhighgui` refers. I found in the manual of g++ that the `-l` flag specifies the library name avoiding `lib` prefix and `*.a` `*.so` (linux)/`*.dylib` (mac) suffix. After executing otool `-L` executable I get the output:

- `/opt/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.3.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.1.0, current version 3.1.0)`

So why it is using this and not other one and which are the way it is used? What are the difference between the three libraries?

Another question is about the linking and executing process. I have understood the linking process when using static libraries. My problem is when compiling dynamic libraries. In the next example:

-Input: `g++ -I/opt/local/include/opencv -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lopencv_highgui image-conversion.cpp -o image-conversion`

I found that the process from compiling to executing a program could be divided in three parts.

- First compiler look for header files below standard directories or directories pass through `-I` flag to make the code parsing.
- Second it links the library specify by `-lflag`, under the path -L or standard paths.  This is done with the linker (ld)
- Third, when executing, the dynamic linker program (dyld) is the program which takes care of "adding" the code to the RAM memory so it executes.

The question is the next one: I have found some people  on internet that say that if they do not set the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (in linux) or `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (in mac OSx) with the non-standard directory of the library (in my case would be `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/local/lib"`), the dynamic linker cannot find the library and the program execution fails. What I found is that my program does not crash and if I execute otool (which is used to see what is linked).I get this (this is a summary of all the libraries that are linked):

`/opt/local/lib/libopencv_shape.3.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.1.0, current version 3.1.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.3.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.1.0, current version 3.1.0)
    ...
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)`

What is happening? I have found that LD_LIBRARY_PATH can be used to test new libraries but why is this people saying that they need to set this variable only for executing the program? How this last part works?. I do not set it and it works perfectly.

Thanks to anyone.

Comment: Usually those other libraries with similiar names are actually symlinks to the file with the long name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two questions (which is not considered a very good SO practice, btw), so I will answer them independently.

Also, I will be focusing on Linux - this is the area I am familiar with. From the text of the question, I assume things are very similar in Mac world.

### Library naming convention

When working with .so linraries in Linux environment, one often sees that dynamic libraries are often presented in triplets. For example, library foo might be exist in 3 files: *libfoo.so*, *libfoo.so.6*, *libfoo.so.6.5.4*. If you look carefully, you will see they are all the same file - usually two of them are just symbolic links to the third one. For the sake of further discussion, libfoo.so will be referred as *unversioned* library, ibfoo.so.6 as *major-versioned* and libfoo.so.6.5.4 *full-versioned. Why do you need those? For better version control.

When you link your application, you always use a linker rule for unversioned livbary - taking into account fact that linker adds `lib` and `.so` to the rule, it would look like

```
g++    ... -lfoo ...
```

When your application is linked, linker opens libfoo.so and checks it for several things. On of the things it checks is a so-called `SONAME` header. This header is created when the .so library is linked, and it can have a different file name from the one linker currently looking at. For example, it might be have a major-versioned file in it, and linker will see it: SONAME = libfoo.so.6.

When linker sees that SONAME, it will mark the resulting application file to require `libfoo.so.6` - even when you actually asked for `libfoo.so`.

By doing so linker preserved the certain version of the library. Your application was initially compiled and linked with version 6, so whenever application is run, version 6 is required.

If later the system is upgraded (or application runs on a different system) where `foo` is of a different version (say, 7), the .so files would be different: *libfoo.so*, *libfoo.so.7*, *libfoo.so.7.6.5*. Since your app needs `libfoo.so.6`, it will fail to start - and this is a good thing, since who knows is version 7 is still compatible? Without this protection application would start and use a different library version, and the effect might've been devastating.

### LD_LIBRARY_PATH search

Your second question is for LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This is true, run-time linker consults this variable when looking for dynamic libraries. However, it is not the only thing it consults. Apart from that, and from default search path, there is also a per-application dynamic libraries path, wich is recorded in the application when it is linked, usually controlled by rpath argument to the linker, like:

```
g++ ... -Wl,rpath,/path/to/so/library
```

When path is recorded like this, the run-time linker will add those paths to the list of search paths when application is loaded.

The fact that libraries can be found for you application without LD_LIBRARY_PATH means one of two things: rpath was recorded when the application was linked, or `/opt/local/lib` is actually included in default search paths on your platform.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think that the rpath is the answer because I use other dynamic libraries for example cudNN for Deep Learning with CUDA and never set LD_LIBRARY_PATH